# Combination of list-ref and index-of in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define code 
  '(
    function f1 < a b >
    vars x y
    begin
      "..."
    end
  )
)

(define ,(cadr code) '()) ;first method

(define ,(list-ref code (+ (index-of code 'function) 1)) '()) ;second method
```

Why does the second method give the warning "define: not an identifier, identifier with default, or keyword for procedure argument" even though both `,(cadr code)` and `,(list-ref code (+ (index-of code 'function) 1))` return `f1`?

Comment: What do you think a comma does in Scheme? your code doesn't make much sense; I suggest you take a look at these docs: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is read, expanded and then evaluated.
The unquote (,) syntax is handled by the reader.
This means, that when you write:

```
(define ,(cadr code) '())
```

in you program, it is equivalent to writing:

```
(define (unquote (cadr code)) '())
```

Which we can write as:

```
(define (unquote [cadr code]) 
   '())
```

So here you define a function named `unquote` that takes one optional argument named `cadr`. The default argument for `cadr` is `code`.

Now you write:

```
(define ,(list-ref code (+ (index-of code 'function) 1)) '())
```

which the reader turns into:

```
(define (unquote (list-ref code (+ (index-of code 'function) 1)))
     '())
```

We see here that `(list-ref code (+ (index-of code 'function) 1))`
is highlighted with the error:

> define: not an identifier, identifier with default, or keyword for procedure argument in:

This meant that `define` expected an indentifier, or [identifier default] or an #: keyword.

If we check the grammar, we see:

```
(λ kw-formals body ...+)

 
kw-formals =  (arg ...)
           |  (arg ...+ . rest-id)
           |  rest-id

arg = id
    | [id default-expr]
    | keyword id
    | keyword [id default-expr]
```

So the error message just means that whatever follows the name of a function
needs to be one of the four case in the grammar for `arg`.

Note: The `unquote` character , is meant to be used inside a quasiquote (a backtick) [look unquote up in the docs].